# How do I set a particular navbar's collapse point in Bootstrap 3?

Tags: css, twitter-bootstrap, twitter-bootstrap-3

Is it possible to set the navbar collapse breakpoint for a *particular* navbar in Bootstrap 3? I have a sub-navbar on my site that looks great down to 500px, and I'd rather not settle for a btn-group.

What I have right now: I've set up an ID for my navbar, and I'd like to use `#toolbar .navbar{` to target that ID. Is there anything in Bootstrap that would allow me to target this selectively?

```
        <div class="navbar navbar-default" id = "toolbar">
        <ul class="nav navbar-nav">
        <li><a href="#"; ?>"> Back</a></li>
        <li><a href="#"> Add</a></li>
        <li><a href="#"> Delete</a></li>
        </ul>
        </div>
```

Comment: Can you post your code so that we know what you've tried so far?

Comment: Done! I don't know what (if anything) can be done on the CSS side.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From the [Bootstrap docs](http://getbootstrap.com/components/#navbar):

> Change the point at which your navbar switches between collapsed and horizontal mode. Customize the @grid-float-breakpoint variable or add your own media query.

In order to create your own media query, you'll need to look at the LESS [here](https://github.com/twbs/bootstrap/blob/master/less/navbar.less#L184) and create your own rules for `#toolbar`.

Comment: `@grid-float-breakpoint` is a LESS variable, though. I don't want to change breakpoints globally, just for one navbar.